# How to put new record in new line in csv file in java

Tags: java

I m trying to create CSV file.But in resulting file all records are shown in one line. How to put the new records on new line

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(line);
 result.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Append a new line in each iteration

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    result.append(line).append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(line);
 result.append(line);
 result.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: And both append's in one line :)

Answer (score 1):

To append a platform independent new line use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

The resulting code would be:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    result.append(line);
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

If you would use a BufferedWriter to write to the file, you can also call "newLine()" to append a line feed.

Comment: What is result for a kind of object? Do close the stream properly?

Answer (score 0):

you may use it`System.out.printf();`: